# Customize "tar --list" date format

Tags: tar, timestamps

This is tar's output when listing files in a tarball:

```
> tar zvtf my.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- myuser/mygroup  2363 2018-05-03 15:45 test.txt
```

Is there any way to customize the date format to print out high-res epoch seconds, like "1537492797.82289"?

The version of tar is:

```
> tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't any, at least not with gnu tar.

Here is how the date is formatted ([`tartime()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/list.c#n1052) in `tree/src/list.c`)

> ```
> if (tm)
>   {
>     if (full_time)
>         {
>         strftime (buffer, sizeof buffer, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tm);
>         code_ns_fraction (ns, buffer + strlen (buffer));
>         }
>     else
>         strftime (buffer, sizeof buffer, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tm);
>     return buffer;
>   }
> ```

And here is how the file header is printed ([`simple_print_header()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/list.c#n1253) in `tree/src/list.c`):

> ```
> fprintf (stdlis, "%s %s/%s %*s %-*s",
>          modes, user, group, ugswidth - pad + sizelen, size,
>          datewidth, time_stamp);
> ```

Comment: Thank you for backing up your answer with the tar source.